# Frame used for RGB cube in SAOImage

Tags: software, image-processing, fits

I have RGB FITS images with NAXIS=3 so I read them into SAOImage (ds9 8.2.1). I use this command line:

```
$ ds9 -rgbcube myimage.fits
```

Doing so, the window is split in two frames, one empty and the second with my image. I tried this:

```
$ ds9 -frame delete -rgbcube myimage.fits
```

Now I have only one frame as wanted but it is numbered 2 since the frame 1 has been deleted by the `-frame delete`. My question is: is it possible to simply load the RGB cube into frame 1 or rename frame 2 to frame 1?

Thanks if you can help me!